# float to long conversion increasing the value

Tags: java, floating-point

I am storing a long value comes from backend system and I had to convert it to float because of one of the third party api only understands float.
Now when I read back the float and trying to convert back to long I am getting a bigger number(some times I've seen smaller as well)than what I had.

My question is how can I get back the original number in long. I am happy to add any rounding logic if required

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        long item = 1502028000;

        System.out.println(String.format("item -> %d",item));

        float floatItem = item;

        System.out.println(String.format("floatItem ->  %f",floatItem));

        long resultItem = (long)floatItem;

        System.out.println(String.format("resultItem ->  %d",resultItem));

    }
}
```

Below is the output. I need my original number back which is 1502028000 in this case.

```
item -> 1502028000
floatItem ->  1502028032.000000
resultItem ->  1502028032
```

Comment: You cannot long-float is a lossy conversion (also float-long).

Comment: Can you use `double` instead?

Comment: No only I have option of using float . I can't modify the third-party API. Can we do some Math.round or something to get the original number back

Comment: @Bulu No, you can't.

Comment: @GáborBakos [Sure it would.](http://ideone.com/5KlxJ1)

Comment: @GáborBakos Nor would I.

Comment: I am going to do round up or down by 1000 as it's for sure the number of is always multiple of 1000 Math.round(value/1000)*1000

Comment: Could you make a scientific notation class that uses a long to represent the exponent and number and write methods for adding subtracting multiplying and converting to a long?

Comment: Which third-party API could reasonably use floats? That's the problem. You may consider filing a ticket at them?

Comment: You say you have to convert it to float and, at some point in time, read back the float. Does that mean that you store the float and then retrieve it to pass it to the 3rd party API? If so, can't you rather store the long? Or do you get the float back from the 3rd party API? Does that API process the float, or just store it, somehow? If it does not process it, you may be able to pass two or more floats that, together, contain the long (that would involve some casting and some bit "magic").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A float value only has ~24 significant bits, a long has 64 bits. So it must happen that some/many different long values are giving the same float value. And that can't be recovered.

You said that your longs always are multiples of 1000. So of the many longs that correspond to your given float, only those divisibe by 1000 are valid for you. That's what your rounding suggestion `Math.round(value/1000)*1000` will use. But that only works until there are more than 1000 longs mapping to one float, and that happens around the 10 billion magnitude. Your example is just a factor of ten below that, so that won't help reliably if the numbers can grow.

If you REALLY MUST map back the float value to the original long (ask yourself: why is it necessary - can I do my job another way?), you might maintain a Map from Float values to the original Long values wherever you pass a long to the third-party library. IF the long values are sparse, there are chances that within the valid long values that you used, you can often map back from float without ambiguity.

But that's a nasty kludge. Be prepared to deal with the ambiguity if it arises.

Comment: While that is almost true (those ~24 significant bits), it is not the whole truth. The fact that floats have an exponent means that other values can also be represented, but not all of them. I would have pointed out that a float generally has 32 bits, so it is clear it can't have a different representation for every 64 bit value. Due to the way it is made up, it can also represent pretty large values, but not all of them accurately.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that a `float` value is only precise to about 7 digits. In terms of the the `long` value you are converting to a float, that means the `float` can only retain the first 7 digits of 1502028000. Note those 7 are still retained in the float value and when when you convert back to a long.

If you would like to read more about float precision you should take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). Just as an exercise, you could do the same thing with a `double` and more digits should be retained.

Comment: A double only happens for the cases you are giving it but it would also break at some point. It's just has a higher precision because if is represented by 64 bits not 32 like a float

Answer (score 0):

It appears that float doesn't have enough size to convert a "long" value and thus while converting, it looses it's precision.

To resolve this, you can use double instead of float. That will retain your value after the double conversion you are doing.

```
long item = 1502028000;
double floatItem = (double)item;
long resultItem = (long)floatItem;
System.out.println(String.format("resultItem ->  %d",resultItem));
```

This prints :

```
resultItem ->  1502028000
```

Comment: Even double won't be enough for the whole value range of long.